# JDBC connection between Docker containers (docker-compose)

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, docker, jdbc

I try to connect a web application which runs on a tomcat 8 to an oracle database. Both of them run as Docker containers:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  appweb:
   build: ./app
   image: "servlet-search-app:0.1"
   ports:
    - "8888:8080"
   links:
    - appdb
   environment:
    - DATA_SOURCE_NAME="jdbc:oracle:thin:@appdb:1521/XE"

  appdb:
   build: ./db
   image: "servlet-search-db:0.1"
   ports:
    - "49160:22"
    - "1521:1521"
    - "8889:8080"
```

Dockerfile of my oracle DB image (build: ./db):

```
FROM wnameless/oracle-xe-11g
ADD createUser.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
ENV ORACLE_ALLOW_REMOTE=true
```

Dockerfile of the tomcat image (build: ./app)

```
FROM tomcat:8.0.20-jre8
COPY servlet.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
COPY ojdbc14-1.0.jar /usr/local/tomcat/lib/
```

So the app starts up as expected but throws an exception when trying to connect to the database:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Invalid connection string format, a valid format is: "host:port:sid" 
    org.se.lab.ui.ControllerServlet.createConnection(ControllerServlet.java:115)
    org.se.lab.ui.ControllerServlet.handleSearch(ControllerServlet.java:78)
    org.se.lab.ui.ControllerServlet.doPost(ControllerServlet.java:53)
    org.se.lab.ui.ControllerServlet.doGet(ControllerServlet.java:38)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Now the issue seems obvious, however when I fix the DATA_SOURCE_NAME string to:

```
DATA_SOURCE_NAME="jdbc:oracle:thin:@appdb:1521:XE"
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
appdb:1521:XE"

    org.se.lab.ui.ControllerServlet.createConnection(ControllerServlet.java:115)
    org.se.lab.ui.ControllerServlet.handleSearch(ControllerServlet.java:78)
    org.se.lab.ui.ControllerServlet.doPost(ControllerServlet.java:53)
    org.se.lab.ui.ControllerServlet.doGet(ControllerServlet.java:38)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Now I tried to find out which one of them should actually work. Thus, I started only the DB container:

```
docker build -t dbtest .
docker run -it -d --rm -p 1521:1521 --name dbtest dbtest
docker inspect dbtest | grep IPAddress
>> "IPAddress": "172.17.0.4"
```

Next, I try to connect with sqlplus:

```
sqlplus system/oracle@172.17.0.4:1521/XE # works
sqlplus system/oracle@172.17.0.4:1521:XE #ERROR: ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
```

So what's the problem? Due to the link in the docker-compose file, the tomcat container can resolve "appdb" to the container's IP.

Here's the code which should establish the connection:

```
protected Connection createConnection() {
        String datasource = System.getenv("DATA_SOURCE_NAME");
        try {
            // debug
            InetAddress address = null;
            try {
                address = InetAddress.getByName("appdb");
                System.out.println(address); // resolves in appdb/10.0.0.2
                System.out.println(address.getHostAddress()); // resolves in 10.0.0.2
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            return DriverManager.getConnection(datasource, "system", "oracle");
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
```

Lastly here's the tnsnames.ora file:

```
 cat $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File:

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = fcffb044d69d)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you will have to try to connect without docker images/containers first to make sure the connection with DB establishes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The oracle default listener resolved the configured host to the wrong IP address:

vim $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/listener.ora:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = f4c4a3638c11)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

The HOST value is the Docker container id. If we look at /etc/hosts it is set up correctly for the service link in the docker-compose link:

```
10.0.0.5        f4c4a3638c11
```

It gets also resolved correctly from the tomcat container

```
ping f4c4a3638c11
PING f4c4a3638c11 (10.0.0.5): 56 data bytes
...
```

If I try to connect with an IP address of the other interface, which is the docker interface from the host system, the connection from the web application to the database works

```
String datasource = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.17.0.4:1521:XE";
```

So the solution is to configure the listener to listen to the correct IP address

```
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.0.0.5)(PORT = 1521))
```

Now this connection string works:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@appdb:1521:XE
```

I will report this behavior to wnameless/oracle-xe-11g as a bug

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is not a definitive answer. Let's treat it as long comment :)

Your setup is quite complex for me to recreate however your error message is intriguing:

```
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
appdb:1521:XE"
...
```

It looks like the environment value was chopped to `appdb:1521:XE`. How about if you try hard-coding:

```
String datasource = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@appdb:1521/XE";
```

If that works, then probably need to somehow escape your docker `DATA_SOURCE_NAME` environment variable.

I could be completely wrong but I think it is worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I thought the same. However, this seems to be the common error message.